# Reason behind adding HTML Unit Driver in Selenium 3.0.1

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit-driver, selenium3

As suggested in the below link, selenium has removed HTMLUnitDriver from selenium distribution as per its evolution strategy.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2381

While working on Selenium 3.0.1, i have found that HTMLUnitDriver is again distributed with Selenium server.

Can any one explain why again the HTML Unit driver is added as part of selenium server in Selenium 3. I have checked in Selenium 3.0.1 and Selenium 3.0.0.beta-2 . I did not check in the earlier betas of selenium 3.

The addition the browser driver in selenium distribution collides with the selenium evolution strategy that the browser driver need to be separated from selenium distribution. Can anyone tell me why this is added even if it is aganist the selenium evolution strategy?